# Compiling Python, curses.h not found

Tags: python, configure, curses

I'm attempting to build Python 2.6.2 from source on my Linux system.  It has ncurses installed on /usr/local/, and curses.h is on /usr/local/include/ncurses.  So curses.h isn't found on the include path, and those packages fail in the Python build.

What's the right solution to this?  Is Python supposed to include <ncurses/curses.h>?  Should /usr/local/include/ncurses be in the include path?  Should there be a link from the files in the ncurses directory to /usr/local/include?

Or is there some simpler solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With many Open Source packages, you can set:

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"
```

or even:

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include/ncurses"
```

before running the configure script.  I haven't compiled Python recently enough to be sure that works, but it probably does -- I have ncurses installed under /usr/gnu (because /usr/local/ is automounted and contains antiques) and I don't remember having to use anything special to get it to work.

---

Double-checked...

The configure script only includes `<curses.h>`.  I had to use:

```
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/gnu/include -I/usr/gnu/include/ncurses"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/gnu/lib"
./configure
```

To get the Python (2.5) configure to accept curses.  You'd replace '`gnu`' with '`local`' for your configuration.

Comment: This did the trick for me.  I tried setting CFLAGS and that didn't work, it needed to be CPPFLAGS.  And for me the LDFLAGS wasn't necessary, as libncurses is found on my LD_LIBRARY_PATH okay.  Thank you!

Comment: For Python 3.7, including both `.../include` and `.../include/ncurses` indeed did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but the problem still occurred to me when compiling python 3.6.0 from source so I guess it's still relevant.

Recent versions of ncurses come in several flavors: normal, wide character support, threaded. In order to allow programmers to keep and use different flavors, besides naming the libraries differently (`ncursesw.so`, `ncursest.so`, etc), the ncurses configure script sets up the makefile to put the header files in subdirectories by default. This also allows to have different curses implementations alongside ncurses, as specified in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses).

Some programs, however, still assume that `curses.h`, along all other ncurses headers, are placed in the top level include search paths, and won't look into subdirectories. In many linux distributions there is usually some sort of workaround for the problem in ncurses developement packages, but if you are compiling ncurses from source, there are two possible approaches to solve the issue:

1. Using `CPPFLAGS` or equivalent, as the accepted answer suggests. It works, but you have to set the appropriate compilation flags every time.
2. Configuring ncurses with `--enable-overwrite`. This will install the ncurses header files in the top level include directory, according to your `--prefix`.

If you don't plan to install an alternate curses library, it's completely  safe to put the ncurses headers in the top level include path, and it is the approach followed by [Gentoo](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/sys-libs/ncurses/ncurses-6.0-r1.ebuild).

Comment: There are differences across the headers, e.g., `sizeof(WINDOW)` when comparing ncurses/ncursesw.  And of course ncurses5/ncurses6 uses different bitmasks for the mouse.

Comment: @ThomasDickey I was merely assessing compatibility, not identity. Apparently, the man page states that the headers are source-compatible. Regardless, I have stripped my answer of that information, as it is not part of the question.